# accordion stops working with update panel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

i have a accordion control(using jQuery) on the page. When I insert accordion into an updatepanel, set a button outside the `updatepanel` as its trigger and click on the button the accordion stops working. If I remove the updatepanel, it starts working.

Why?
How can i fix this error?
Do i have to re-instantiate the accordion script/plugin, If yes then how?

```
<script src="Scripts/ddaccordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   ddaccordion.init({
        headerclass: "silverheader", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
        contentclass: "submenu", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
        revealtype: "mouseover", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
        mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
        collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false
        defaultexpanded: [0], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content
        onemustopen: true, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
        animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
        persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
        toggleclass: ["", "selected"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
        togglehtml: ["", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
        animatespeed: "fast", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
        oninit: function(headers, expandedindices) { //custom code to run when headers have initalized
            //do nothing
        },
        onopenclose: function(header, index, state, isuseractivated) { //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
            //do nothing
        }
    })
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <div class="applemenu">
        <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Dynamic Drive</a></div>
        <div class="submenu">
            Some random content here<br />
       </div>
       <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/" >CSS Examples</a></div>
       <div class="submenu">
            Some random content here<br />
       </div>
       <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></div>
       <div class="submenu">
            Some random content here<br />
       </div>
       <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></div>
       <div class="submenu">
           Some random content here<br />
          <img src="http://i27.tinypic.com/sy7295.gif" />
       </div>
       <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></div>
       <div class="submenu">
           Some random content here<br />
       </div>       
     </div>    
   </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
         </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

When elements are removed from the DOM their event handlers go with them, even if you replace those with identical elements. You need to re-initialize the event handlers, or look into using jQuery's `.live()` functionality.

Comment: `function pageLoad(sender, args)

{

    if(args.get_isPartialLoad())

    {

        $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");

    }

}` how can i use the above function to load the jQuery script on Asynchronous postbacks

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain the structure of the Jquery widget.
I achieved what you want by surrounding the controls I want within the sub-divs of the accordion div with update panels.
Hence, you should maintain the following structure:

1. Accordion Div
2. Heading 3 caption for the sub div 1
3. div 1
4. **update panel**
5. div 1 contents that will be refreshed using Ajax technology.

And so on, of course you need the Script Manager so don't forget to insert one :)